# Declare typescript interface props in vue.js component

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-props

I want to define vue component props with in a single object in typescript.

```
import {Component, Prop, Vue} from 'vue-property-decorator'

export class Props extends Vue
{
  classElement :string
}

@Component
export default class Menu extends Vue<Props>
{
    public props :Props;

    .....
}
```

I can do this like above in class based component.

But how can I do this in component using Vue.extend()?

Answer (score 1):

Try this syntax

```js
props: {
  foo: {
    type: Object as () => IFoo
  }
}
```